# SSL AJAX jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, https, struts2

Spec
Apache2,Tomcat6,jdk1.6,struts2,Ajax,jQuery

My question :

A web site working **perfectly on Http mode(apache2 http + tomcat + struts2 )**

is **NOT able to work in Https (apache2 https + tomcat + struts2)**

Has ajax /Jquery got to do any thing with SSL enabling ???

with regards
Karthik

Comment: What does "Not able to work" mean ... what errors ? what problems ?

Comment: Are all the HTTP requests in one domain or is their cross domain activity going on?  Sites often have problems when cross domain requests are involved.

Comment: Quick answer: "NO", now what ELSE is involved that is causing the issue...need more details.

Comment: @N.S.Karthik: Provides complete information as no one is going to guess what you mean by *Not able to work*

Comment: Hi
Sorry for delay 

My Intranet Application hosted on http as per client request works perfectly normally on the setup defined.

Apache 2x (http) + Tomcat 6 (web container) + tomcat-connectors-1.2.32-windows-i386-httpd-2.2.x


But when i switch on to SSL ( locally generated Open SSL ) from

Http to Https ....the Site breaks up.

Our Application 85% uses jQuery,Ajax,Struts2 for application.

I am now in delima why this is happening.....

Comment: >>Provides complete information as no one is going to guess what you mean by Not able to work

I mean Https is BLANK screen with response 200
Error LOGS do not dsiplay any thing unusal....

Comment: @N.S.Karthik - can you run the page with some development tools open, for example Firebug in Firefox to see if you get any errors logged to the error console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ajax mixing HTTP and HTTPS even on the same domain violates the [Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as it is a different protocol and a different port.

You have to provide all your content by the same server instance (same domain, port and protocol).

Comment: Hi My Intranet Application hosted on http as per client request works perfectly normally on the setup defined. Apache2x(http)+Tomcat6(webcontainer)+tomcat-connectors-1.2.32-86-httpd-2.2.x,But when switch on to SSL( locally generated Open SSL )from Http to Https.the Site breaks up.Apache2x(https)+Tomcat6(web container)+tomcat-connectors-1.2.32-httpd-2.2.x.Our Application 85% uses jQuery,Ajax,Struts2 for application.

Comment: I am now in delima why this is happening.....Digging deep into the application I could not find any breakups which lead to non performance issue.Are there any Specific protocol API's not to be used in jQuery,Ajax,Struts for Https and Http ....??

Answer (score 2):

Neither AJAX or jQuery care whether you are using HTTPS or HTTP. The only thing to watch out for is if you mix HTTP and HTTPS, i.e. you have an HTTPS page, but your `src` attributes for your script includes have `http://` rather than `https://`

If you have tested the same page and scripts on HTTP and it works, then you probably aren't encountering a cross-site scripting issue, as that would be an issue on HTTP and HTTPS.

Therefore, it is likely that something else is causing a problem - can you provide more details of the error?

Comment: Hi
>> you have an HTTPS page, but your src attributes for your script includes have http:// rather than https://

All our Js files are loaded with relative hidden path as "<javasript src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

There is no other Cross-site scripts within out application ,if any available within Jquery lib need to be verified..